# How add style of cell and change properties of <td> in adding row

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add row and change the style of it. I use javascript to add cell and row, but I can't change style the of cell and can't change the property of new row.

Any one please suggest to change it. Let my script is

```
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var row = table.insertRow(5);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
cell4.innerHTML = "NEW CELL4";
```

Comment: Where have you applied the style ?

Comment: Mr. Shrestha you can change the cell style using Javascript . For example `cell.style.textAlign = "center";`

Comment: See this list for a mapping between the css styles and the javascript names: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference
Or set `element.className = 'myclass';`

Comment: thank u. what about height,width and bgcolor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the height and color like this :

```
document.getElementById('dataTable').style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";
document.getElementById('dataTable').style.height="50";
document.getElementById('dataTable').style.textAlign="center";
```

Comment: for alignment 
row.style.align="center"; is not working. plz suggest how to do

Comment: document.getElementById("dataTable").style.textAlign = "center";
 Please give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

> Use `element.style.property='value'` to set the style of the element.

If there are multiple `css` properties to be assigned then use `classes`(`.className`) over `.style.propertyName`

Try this:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
cell4.innerHTML = "NEW CELL4";
cell1.className = 'yourClass';
cell2.className = 'yourClass';
cell3.className = 'yourClass';
cell4.className = 'yourClass';
```

```css
.yourClass {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF
}
```

```html
<table id='dataTable'>
  <table>
```

Comment: i want to add height="50" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" inside tag <td>